# How to get IdentityUser roles' names in View?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, navigation-properties, ef-fluent-api

Using ASP.NET MVC5 user identity, I am trying to display IdentityUser's role names in view.

It seems like Identity user has Roles property, which represent collection of `IdentityUserRole`, instead of `IdentityRole`. The difference is `IdentityUserRole` represents association between `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`, while `IdentityRole` is the actual `Role` model **<sup>[[+]](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx#A-Note-About-IdentityRole-and-IdentityUserRole)</sup>**. Apparently there is no navigation defined between IdentityUser and IdentityRole. So all we get is RoleId from `IdentityUserRole`.

1. Is there an easy way to get the roles names?
2. Using Fluent API, can we define a virtual navigation property between `IdentityRole` and `IdentityUserRole` to get name easily
   throughout the project?
3. If it is by design, what is the benefit of not letting us obtain `IdentityRole` straightforwardly?

Comment: I would suggest you to get roles in controller / action and pass it to the view as a property, that means part of the model you are passing to view. If not you may need to extend IPrincipal or IIdentity properties to include Roles, then you can get it something like HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Roles.

Comment: I'm assuming that you found an answer to this by now even though there is nothing here so I'd like to know what it is.  At this point I am storing a dictionary representation of the IdentityRole objects in the ViewBag and accessing them by IdentityUserRole.RoleId in the view code.  It works but I am not thrilled with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can select a userrole in identity using the rolemanager

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(this.dbcontext));
```

from the user get the userrole and then select the name from that role

```
roleManager.FindById(user.RoleId).Name
```